# run command and input parameter failed

Tags: c#

I want to put password on that right position according to this picture.

I don't know how to put it there please advise

I use this methods to start cmd [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/720259/How-to-run-command-prompt-command-and-get-output-i)

and I use this methods to sent the command...

```
// start process
process.Start();
// send command to its input
using (StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput)
    {
         if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
         {
              sw.WriteLine("C:\\Windows\\System32\\runas.exe /user:xxxxxx\\xxxxx \"C:\\xxxx\\xxx.exe\"");
              sw.WriteLine("password");
              Console.ReadKey();
         }
    }
    //wait
    process.WaitForExit();
```

[image]

Comment: I think the trick is to use Console.Write() instead of Console.WriteLine() for the prompt text, and not have \r\n as the last characters you write.

Comment: It seems like the process is already terminated when your program types in "password". See "1326: The user name or password is incorrect" - could it be that after this line the process is done, and you type "password" back to the standard stdout (in this case, the cmd)?

Comment: Why don't you use the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that takes a username, password and domain?

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: When replying to a comment you should start with "@username". Just type @ and the first letter, then click on the name in the popup. That way the user is notified. Otherwise you will only get a reply if the user happens to remember to come back here. (This time it was OK because rene did come back here, but sometimes it doesn't work so well.)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply the [UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.username(v=vs.100).aspx), [Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.password(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.domain(v=vs.100).aspx) to the [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.100).aspx) to run the exe under different credentials

Pay attention to the password that needs to be a [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/176bafkd(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
 process.StartInfo.UserName ="username";
 process.StartInfo.Domain = "domain"; 

 process.StartInfo.FileName = "YourExeFile.exe";
 process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\path\where\exe\is\";
 process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

 // password    
 char[] chars = "password".ToCharArray();
 // Instantiate a new secure string.
 fixed(char* pChars = chars)
 {
    process.StartInfo.Password = new SecureString(pChars, chars.Length);
 }

 process.Start();
```

With this there is no need to use runas and fiddle with error prone input and outputstream handling.

Comment: I have read your solution again and again around 5 hours. At last I can know and understand how to use it thx! @rene